# I am trying to measure the change in size a piece of ceramic using a camera

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, measurement

I am trying to measure the change in size a piece of ceramic as it is heated, I am attempting to do this using a camera and edge detection. To test this I am firstly using an image taken from the camera (image below) and hopefully transitioning to a live video feed later.[image: ceramic at room temp]

Here is the canny image, I would ideally like to get the contours to follow the entire edge of the ceramic piece and be able to measure the length of the sides and the area.[canny image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WqiG.png)

I have been using canny and some other image processing algorithms to define the edges, these will then be using to find and grab contours to then loop over these using a bounding box to measure the size (in pixels), but this is proving to be difficult. I am completely new to this and have been using mainly tutorials, the code below shows some of the image preprocessing I have been attempting. Is there a better way of doing this? can you measure the length of contours without a bounding box?

Any help is appreciated.

## *Image preprocessing*

```
img = cv2.imread('buller_ring_test.jpg') 
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(img, 110, 255)
#imggrey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
#imgThre = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imggrey, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2) 
#imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 1) imgCanny = cv2.Canny(img, 110, 255) plt.figure(figsize = (15,15)) plt.imshow(imgCanny)
```

## *Looping over contours*

```
#find the total contours
conts = cv2.findContours(imgThre,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#fine tune contours
conts = imutils.grab_contours(conts)
print (len(conts))

#create empty image with original dimensions
conts_img = np.zeros(img.shape)
plt.imshow(conts_img)

#draw contours onto the rmpty image to isolate contours
conts_img = cv2.drawContours(conts_img, conts, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
plt.imshow(conts_img)

#draw contours onto the rmpty image to isolate contours
#create the empty image with original dimensions
conts_img = np.zeros(img.shape)

def midPoint(ptA, ptB):
    return ((ptA[0] + ptB[0])/2, (ptA[1] + ptB[1])/2)



#loop over all the contours coordinates
for c in conts:
    #extract box points
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(box)
    #convert the box points into integer
    box = np.array(box, dtype = int)
    #print(box)
    
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 10: #anything above this number gets used
        continue

    #draw the contour c (it will loop over all individual c's to make conts_img)
    cv2.drawContours(conts_img, [c], -1, (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.drawContours(conts_img, [box], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

    print(box)
    for (x,y) in box:
        cv2.circle(conts_img, (x, y), 2, (255, 0, 0), 1)
        print(x,y)
        (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
        
        #calcualte midPoints for top & bottom
        (tlX, trX) = midPoint(tl, tr)
        (brX, blX) = midPoint(bl, br)
        #draw midPoint dots for top & bottom
        cv2.circle(conts_img, (int(tlX), int(trX)), 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(conts_img, (int(brX), int(blX)), 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        #calculate the distance based on the midPoints
        dA = dist.euclidean((tlX, trX), (brX, blX)) #width
        #print the size in px on each contour rectangle
        cv2.putText(conts_img, '{:.1f} px'.format(dA), (int(tlX)-40, int(trX)-40),
         cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        
        #calcualte midPoints for left & right
        (tlX, trX) = midPoint(tl, bl)
        (brX, blX) = midPoint(tr, br)
        #draw midPoint dots for left & right
        cv2.circle(conts_img, (int(tlX), int(trX)), 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(conts_img, (int(brX), int(blX)), 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        #calculate the distance based on the midPoints
        dB = dist.euclidean((tlX, trX), (brX, blX)) #height
        #print the size in px on each contour rectangle
        cv2.putText(conts_img, '{:.1f} px'.format(dB), (int(brX)-40, int(blX)-40),
         cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        



#show the processed image with the contours printed
plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
plt.imshow(conts_img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: have a look at [Contour Features](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html). The contours method has a whole toolkit to find centroids, best fit bounding box etc...

Comment: please change the title to something a) shorter b) that will be helpful for others with a similar problem in the future

Comment: please present two pictures that only differ in the thing you want to measure. point out what's changing. -- let's start from the beginning and ignore all that code for now.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: (1) Canny edge detection is to detect edges, not closed contours or objects. Look for better methods, some key words: active contours, level sets, graph-cut segmentation. (2) The problem will be a lot easier (trivial even) if you can improve the lighting and background. Make the background uniform and contrasting (e.g. very dark), and illuminate the object so there are no shadows and it has a uniform light appearance. Now finding the object is a matter of thresholding.